# How to navigate a grid looking for close proximity?

Tags: java, search, grid

I have a grid that is declared like:

```
PlayerStatus enum
{
  OCCUPIED,
  VACANT
}

PlayerStatus[][] grid_ = new PlayerStatus[200][200];
```

The grid is set equal to all vacant except where players located at.

I would like to have a method that tells me if a player is in a certain grid proximity of another player, something like:

```
boolean inRange(int x, int y, int range)
{
  //This method finds if a player is close to another one
}
```

So if I pass into `inRange(10, 15, 5)` and at `10, 19` there is a player I would like the method to return true; where as `10, 21` would return false.

Are there any algorithms that do this kind of searching that I could look into? Or does anyone have any solutions?  I feel that calculating diagonals and such will be rather hard, what should I do for that?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your algorithm depends on how you define distance.  If it's a straight line, then the Pythagorean theorem is the way to do it.  If "distance" is composed of lattice straight-line segments only then Pythagoras will give you the wrong answer.  Consider the points (0,0) and (3,3).  By Pythagoras the distance is sqrt(18), which is less than 5, but on the lattice the distance is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.hypot()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29) is a good choice for implementing the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). There's an example here named [`norm()`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#Vector), which is used in this [`KineticModel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel).

Comment: Assumes a [Euclidean metric in two dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions).